# What is commonly stored in the "Other" section of resource files?

Tags: .net, resource-files

I was looking through a .NET [resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f45fce5x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. a .resx file) and it is has a number of sections which make sense for common uses of a resource:

- Strings
- Images
- Icons (aren't these just images too?)
- Audio
- Files
- Other

For the life of me, I can't think of anything that would need other, since the other options seem to cover everything.

My question is, what are common uses for 'Other' in a resource file?

[image: screen grab of resource file]

Answer (score 0):

"Displays a settings grid for adding other types that support string serialization (for example, Font, Enum, Color, and Point). The grid contains the following columns: Name, Type, Value, and Comment. For a description of the columns in this grid, see "Settings Grid," below."

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69a74ty(v=vs.80).aspx